# Downloading png file from fileoutputstream

Tags: javascript, image, file, download

I am trying to download a png file to computer which is taken as a fileoutputstream. I am trying this code:

```
var userid = this.userid;
  let link = null;
  function reqListener() {
    if (this.responseText !== undefined) {
       link = document.createElement("a");
      var blob = new Blob([this.responseText], { type: item.type });
      link.download = item.name;
      link.href = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      debugger;
      link.click();

    }
  }
}
```

It downloads a file but it cannot be opened. It gets error that it cannot be loaded as png. It works with other types of files but doesn't work with image files. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>');
```

#### Media Types for Images

- image/gif
- image/jpeg
- image/png
- image/svg+xml
- image/x-icon, image/vnd.microsoft.icon (For Windows Icons)

#### Base64

**data:,Hello%2C%20World!**

Simple, text/plain data

**data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D**

base64-encoded version of the above

### What do you need?

You need, this string for `href` attribute,

```
link.setAttribute('href', `data:image/png;base64,${btoa(this.responseText)}`)
```